# Linear transformation from endormorphism to real number

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

For a finite dimensional vector space $V$, is there a linear transformation between its endomorphism and real number, please? I suspect that since the element of the endomorphism can be represented by a square matrix given a basis, then the question becomes to find a liner transformation from a set of matrix to real number. One such thing I can think of is determinant. Is this guess true, please?

Answer (score 1):

the determinant is not exactly linear, it is is multilinear. It is simpler to take just the first coordinate of your matrix.